# Flutter build failed: Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

Tags: android, flutter

Got the following error message while trying to run the project.

I am trying to run my code after almost 4-6 months. And ended up with this error. I have used compileSdkVersion 33 and flutter latest release.

```
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/yaseen/development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1157

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDevRelease'.
> Process 'command '/home/yaseen/development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevRelease'...                        19.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDevRelease failed with exit code 1
#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
#1      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:408:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      AndroidGradleBuilder.buildApk (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:184:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      AndroidDevice.startApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_device.dart:574:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterDevice.runCold (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:518:33)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      ColdRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/run_cold.dart:57:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:715:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#7      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1257:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#8      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:209:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#10     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:283:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:229:5)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#14     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#15     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:91:3)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

Any help would be appreciatable.

I was trying to run the project but failed with no luck.